# Types when destructuring arrays

Tags: arrays, types, typescript, destructuring

```
function f([a,b,c]) {
  // this works but a,b and c are any
}
```

it's possible write something like that?

```
function f([a: number,b: number,c: number]) {
  // being a, b and c typed as number 
}
```

Answer (score 201):

This is the proper syntax for destructuring an array inside an argument list:

```
function f([a,b,c]: [number, number, number]) {

}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: If all the parameters are of the same type, can you shorten this syntax? Something in the lines of f([a, b, c]: [number]) {...}

Comment: @filipbarak `f([a, b, c]: number[])`

Answer (score 17):

Yes, it is. In TypeScript, you do it with types of array in a simple way, creating tuples.

```
type StringKeyValuePair = [string, string];
```

You can do what you want by naming the array:

```
function f(xs: [number, number, number]) {}
```

But you wouldn't name the interal parameter.
Another possibility is use destructuring by pairs:

```
function f([a,b,c]: [number, number, number]) {}
```

Answer (score 12):

With TypeScript 4.0, tuple types can now provide labels

```
type Range = [start: number, end: number]
```

Answer (score 7):

my code was something like below

```
type Node = { 
    start: string;
    end: string;
    level: number;
};

const getNodesAndCounts = () => { 
    const nodes : Node[]; 
    const counts: number[];
    // ... code here

return [nodes, counts];
}

const [nodes, counts] = getNodesAndCounts(); // problematic line needed type
```

typescript was giving me error in line below TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature;

```
nodes.map(x => { 
//some mapping; 
    return x;
);
```

Changing line to below resolved my problem;

```
const [nodes, counts] = <Node[], number[]>getNodesAndCounts();
```

Answer (score 5):

As a simple answer I would like to add that you can do this:

```
function f([a,b,c]: number[]) {}
```