# What is the proper way to assign types when destructuring `callbackFn.currentValue` while using `.reduce()`?

Tags: typescript, annotations, destructuring

I have an array of arrays (e.g.

```
const input = [['A', 'X'], ['B', 'Y'],...];
```

). I also have two `enum`s:

```
  enum MyMove {
    Rock = 'X',
    Paper = 'Y',
    Scissors = 'Z',
  };

  enum OpponentMove {
    Rock = 'A',
    Paper = 'B',
    Scissors = 'C',
  };
```

I want to run a `Array.prototype.reduce()` on `input`, but I can't figure out how to annotate `callbackFn.currentValue`. I want to do something like this:

```
  const score: number = input.reduce(
    (acc: number, ([opponentMove, myMove]: [OpponentMove, MyMove])) => {
```

(based on [Types when destructuring arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31923739/types-when-destructuring-arrays)), but I'm getting the following errors:

```
02/index.ts:38:9 - error TS2322: Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'number'.

38   const score: number = input.reduce(
           ~~~~~
02/index.ts:39:21 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'opponentMove'.

39     (acc: number, ([opponentMove, myMove]: [OpponentMove, MyMove])) => {
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~
02/index.ts:39:35 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'myMove'.

39     (acc: number, ([opponentMove, myMove]: [OpponentMove, MyMove])) => {
                                     ~~~~~~
02/index.ts:39:44 - error TS2554: Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 3.

39     (acc: number, ([opponentMove, myMove]: [OpponentMove, MyMove])) => {
                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

What is the proper way to annotate `[opponentMove, myMove]`?

Comment: I don't understand why you need to annotate at all... you didn't show the whole callback, but [it should just work as is](https://tsplay.dev/w2p5rm) without annotations.  Or if you must annotate you could do it [this way](https://tsplay.dev/NB4JxW).  Do either of those meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I think I got it, and I think it's related to your question. Instead of annotating inside `callbackFn.currentValue`, I can just cast `input` from `String[][]` to `Array<[OpponentMove, MyMove]>`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of [annotating the callback parameter types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#parameter-type-annotations) in your [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), you should probably properly [annotate the type of the `input` variable](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) in the first place.  For example:

```
const input: Array<[OpponentMove, MyMove]> = [
  [OpponentMove.Rock, MyMove.Rock],
  [OpponentMove.Paper, MyMove.Paper]
];
```

Then the destructured callback parameters to `reduce()` should be [inferred from context](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) automatically:

```
const score: number = input.reduce((
  acc, [opponentMove, myMove]) => 2, 0);
// (parameter) opponentMove: OpponentMove
// (parameter) myMove: MyMove
```

Which is what you wanted.

---

Note that I changed the initialization of `input` from your version, to avoid problems:

```
const input: Array<[OpponentMove, MyMove]> = 
  [['A', 'X'], ['B', 'Y']]; // error!
```

When you have an [`enum`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html), you should only refer to the value through the enum itself.  While, for example, `MyMove.Rock` and `"X"` are the same value at runtime, the TypeScript compiler treats `MyMove.Rock` as a special version of `"X"` and gets upset if you try to use the latter when it expects the former:

```
const oops: MyMove = "X"; // error! Type '"X"' is not assignable to type 'MyMove'.
const okay: MyMove = MyMove.Rock; // okay
```

And while you could use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to "cast" the latter to the former, it is unsafe:

```
const assert = "X" as MyMove; // okay
const whaa = "x" as MyMove; // still okay to the compiler, but this is a mistake
```

So you should be writing this:

```
const input: Array<[OpponentMove, MyMove]> = [
  [OpponentMove.Rock, MyMove.Rock],
  [OpponentMove.Paper, MyMove.Paper]
];
```

That's how `enum`s are intended to behave.  If you're not happy with it, maybe `enum`s aren't really what you want to use.  You could use plain objects and [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) instead.  These behave similarly:

```
const MyMove = {
  Rock: 'X',
  Paper: 'Y',
  Scissors: 'Z',
} as const;
type MyMove = typeof MyMove[keyof typeof MyMove];
// type MyMove = "X" | "Y" | "Z"

const OpponentMove = {
  Rock: 'A',
  Paper: 'B',
  Scissors: 'C',
} as const;
type OpponentMove = typeof OpponentMove[keyof typeof OpponentMove];
// type OpponentMove = "A" | "B" | "C"
```

but then either way of referring to the values will work since, for example, the type of `MyMove.Rock` is just the literal type `"X"` and not a special enum-flavored subtype of it:

```
const input: Array<[OpponentMove, MyMove]> = [
  ["A", "X"], ["B", "Y"]
]; // okay

const input: Array<[OpponentMove, MyMove]> = [
  [OpponentMove.Rock, MyMove.Rock],
  [OpponentMove.Paper, MyMove.Paper]
]; // still okay
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-GCzdu5lspXV2nM+u+ugcyA85nU-m972iiuy2Cu1UN33SZYm-WnM+Nt4uTB2zHO2EItFYniRJUnPTdcgrEASjKAcYBSDYnzyO5OlgjZX0QxtJlwaZ9hpXFv1jUJwkiAAGGI4gSZIeh7MDhlqKCKHKN1YNA1pGlo-pGk6GCqPvfpBk4djRn4zCYGw7EBSFEU8TURQ1AIsRAk4EAYg0H4uB4P9IjqJSABMIDNAAKAzGFNQg8hSJZegvdA8igFFCgASnIUoACY8mIhzVGxAyTQSQ0DC4JzLOo2oYhYnJgG83yWH8wKNRRZFajUZKUuAIA)